# Create insert query from select query by incrementing id

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to copy data from a table and insert into it with some different fields. Here while inserting it results in a problem where I have to specify id(primary key) which is supposed to be auto incrementing but for some reason not set to serial when the tables were created. I wish to add an incrementing id in the data to be inserted based on the already existing data.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
WITH my_admin_id AS
(
  SELECT id
  FROM dashboard_admin
  WHERE email = 'someone@somedomain.com'
),
get_admin AS
(
  SELECT id
  FROM dashboard_admin
  WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM auth_user WHERE username = 'demo')
),
get_admin_projects AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM dashboard_project
  WHERE admin_id IN (SELECT * FROM get_admin LIMIT 1)
  AND   is_deleted = 'false'
) INSERT INTO dashboard_project
(
  SELECT id,
  name,
  created_date,
  (SELECT * FROM my_admin_id LIMIT 1)AS admin_id,
  category_id,
  subcategory_id,
  is_deleted FROM get_admin_projects
)
```

Update :

Earlier the execution of select query meant to be inserted, fetched the following result.

```
67  1stAd   2017-04-21 15:25:16.430889  100 18  47  false
71  2stAd   2017-05-12 10:18:55.383967  100 34  90  false
```

Here I have just added a query to get the max id. I just need to increment it for every record in my final select query.

```
WITH my_admin_id AS
(
  SELECT id
  FROM dashboard_admin
  WHERE email = 'someone@somedomain.com'
),
get_admin AS
(
  SELECT id
  FROM dashboard_admin
  WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM auth_user WHERE username = 'demo')
),
get_max_project AS
(
  SELECT MAX(id) FROM dashboard_project
),
get_admin_projects AS
(
  SELECT id,
         name,
         created_date,
         admin_id,
         category_id,
         subcategory_id,
         is_deleted
  FROM dashboard_project
  WHERE admin_id IN (SELECT * FROM get_admin LIMIT 1)
  AND   is_deleted = 'false'
) (SELECT (SELECT * FROM get_max_project) id,
       name,
       created_date,
       (SELECT * FROM my_admin_id LIMIT 1) AS admin_id,
       category_id,
       subcategory_id,
       is_deleted
FROM get_admin_projects)
```

This is the resultant value on executing the select query.

```
101 1stAd   2017-04-21 15:25:16.430889  100 18  47  false
101 2ndAd   2017-05-12 10:18:55.383967  100 34  90  false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working like this used the row_number() window function which I added to max id , to increment values above max id.

```
WITH my_admin_id AS
(
  SELECT id
  FROM dashboard_admin
  WHERE email = 'someone@somedomain.com'
),
get_admin AS
(
  SELECT id
  FROM dashboard_admin
  WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM auth_user WHERE username = 'demo')
),
get_max_project AS
(
  SELECT MAX(id) FROM dashboard_project
),
get_admin_projects AS
(
  SELECT id,
         name,
         created_date,
         admin_id,
         category_id,
         subcategory_id,
         is_deleted
  FROM dashboard_project
  WHERE admin_id IN (SELECT * FROM get_admin LIMIT 1)
  AND   is_deleted = 'false'
) 
insert into dashboard_project (SELECT ((SELECT * FROM get_max_project)  + row_number() over ()) as id,
       name,
       created_date,
       (SELECT * FROM my_admin_id LIMIT 1) AS admin_id,
       category_id,
       subcategory_id,
       is_deleted
FROM get_admin_projects)
```